# Trying to add elements to list but getting out of range errors

Tags: python, password-encryption

```
import re 

sifrelenmisdizi = []
kelimeler = []
bulunankelimeler = []
input = input("Lütfen Şifrelenmiş Veriyi giriniz : ")
def sifrecoz(message): #im cracking password here
    encrypted = ""
    for i in range(25):
        for char in message:
            value = ord(char) + 1
            valuex = value % 123
            if (valuex <= 0):
                valuex = 97
                encrypted += chr(valuex)
            elif (valuex == 33):
                encrypted += chr(32)
            else:
                encrypted += chr(valuex)

        message = encrypted
        sifrelenmisdizi.append(encrypted)
        encrypted = ""

def kelime_getir(dosya_adi): # here im taking words on "kelimeler.txt" 
    with open(dosya_adi, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
        dosya_icerigi = input_file.read()
        kelime_listesi = dosya_icerigi.split()
        index = 0
        while index <= 1164053:
            kelimeler.append(kelime_listesi[index]) #here im taking that issue
            index += 1
    return kelimeler

sifrecoz(input) 
kelime_getir("kelimeler.txt") 
for i in range(len(kelimeler)):  
    for j in range(len(sifrelenmisdizi)): 
        x = re.split("\s", sifrelenmisdizi[j]) 
        for k in range(len(x)):
            if (kelimeler[i] == x[k]): 
                bulunankelimeler.append(kelimeler[i])
print("Kırılmış şifreniz : ",bulunankelimeler)

# selam daktilo dalga = ugnco eblujmp ebmhb
```

Here I am coding a password cracking program with Caesar decryption of encrypted data and compare with "kelimeler" list.

I'm trying to add words to "kelimeler" list but I'm taking `out of range` error.

This is my word list:
`[URL=https://dosya.co/31174l7qq8zh/kelimeler.txt.html]kelimeler.txt -  16.9 MB[/URL]`

Comment: Try printing `kelime_listesi`... is it actually a list of 1164054 elements? What's the point of appending the list contents to another list? Why is `kelimeler` a global variable, but your function returns it?

Comment: It means that kelime_listesi doesn't have a value at an index you think it does. Why are you hard coding the index value?

Comment: Why not *input_file.readlines()* - That will give you a list of all the words in the file then you don't have to write any code related to its length (which may vary after subsequent downloads)

Comment: Yes, kelime_listesi have 1164054 elements @ddejohn

Comment: @SpiritPony yes kelime_listesi have value like im coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the function *kelime_getir* is expected to return a list of all the words in the file (which has one word per line).

Therefore:

```
def kelime_getir(dosya_adi):
  with open(dosya_adi, encoding='utf-8') as txt:
    return list(map(str.strip, txt))
```

...is all you need

Comment: i cant understand how can i take word list on this func. Is that returning to text file?

Comment: @HarunErkamBalı It returns a list of words from the file. Try it

Comment: @HarunErkamBalı you need to call it like: `wordsList = kelime_getir("words.txt")` where "words.txt" is the text file that contains the words.